# Where does the yanked text on commadline get stored?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

When you delete characters on the command line using readline commands (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd>, you can paste using <kbd>Ctrl-y</kbd>, but where does it get stored? It does not seem to use X11 clipboard at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It goes into a kill-ring, just like in Emacs. From the GNU Readline docuementation:

> When you use a kill command, the text is saved in a kill-ring. Any
>   number of consecutive kills save all of the killed text together, so
>   that when you yank it back, you get it all. The kill ring is not line
>   specific; the text that you killed on a previously typed line is
>   available to be yanked back later, when you are typing another line.

Source: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Killing-Commands.html

The kill ring is stored in memory allocated via `malloc` to a char pointer. From `kill.c` of the readline source:

```
/* Where to store killed text. */
static char **rl_kill_ring = (char **)NULL;
```

Comment: Check out my comment to vonbrand's [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67854/13136).

Comment: @EmanuelBerg I would assume it's stored in memory. The GNU readline source is the best place to find that answer.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg I had a look at the source and update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`readline` is a library for tty use (at least originally), it is completely oblivious to any graphics environment (thus X clipboard or whatnot).

Comment: Do you know where the kill ring is actually stored? Is it a stack (LIFO file) or something else? Can I examine it first hand?